# How do I "push" a variable to another script to cause an action?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity2D C#: I am looking for a way to "push" the chamberName variable from my Chamber script to my GUIManager script so it will actively add it to the text.  I have found 1,000's of ways to pass variables between scripts, but none that actively cause the receiving script to take an action.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post the code and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: C# Events, or UnityEvents, or custom Properties (setters), or function/method calls.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to get a reference to the GameObject with the other script attached, and call a public function in that script which will perform your action.

The [GetComponent tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/getcomponent?playlist=17117) from the Unity website will help you understand this. It's only 3 minutes long and it covers how to get references to components on the same object as the attached script, as well as other objects.